# Exporting within a mapped function in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am quite new to GEE and I am having issues mixing client and server-side functions.
I am importing a table with rain gauge coordinates and their associated IDs as a feature collection. I have defined a function that for each feature:

1. Extract the coordinates, creates a buffer around the point and computes the time series of the mean aerosol absorving index from TROPOMI (Sentinel 5P).
2. Extracts the ID.
3. Exports the time series as a CSV called _aer_ai_timeseries.csv to Google Drive

The function works when I call it only on one feature, but not when I map it. From what I have been reading the problem is that mapping is a server-side function while export is a client-side function. However I am not being able to find a workaround.

What would be the best way to stil run the function on all features in my collection AND export all timeseries?

This is my function:

```
var AER_AI_series = function(feature){
  var lon = feature.geometry().coordinates().get(0);
  var lat = feature.geometry().coordinates().get(1);
  
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)
  
  var geom = point.buffer(3500);
  
  ////////////////        //////////////////
  // IMAGE COLLECTION - SENTINEL 5P - AER_AI
  ////////////////        //////////////////
  
  var start_date_ai = '2018-07-01';
  var end_date_ai = '2022-11-01';
  
  var aer_ai = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_AER_AI')
    .select('absorbing_aerosol_index')
    .filterDate(start_date_ai, end_date_ai);

  
  //////
  // 
  //  CREATING TIME SERIES TO EXPORT TO GOOGLE DRIVE
  //
  //////
  var filteredCollection = aer_ai.select('absorbing_aerosol_index')
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geom));
    
  var timeSeries = ee.FeatureCollection(filteredCollection.map(function(image) {
    var stats = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: geom,
      scale: 3500,
      maxPixels: 1e10
    });
    
    // If there was no aer_ai value found, we set the ndvi to a NoData value -9999
    var aer_ai = ee.List([stats.get('absorbing_aerosol_index'), -9999])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
   
    // Create a feature with null geometry and aer_ai value and date as properties
    var f = ee.Feature(null, {'aer_ai': aer_ai,
      'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd')});
    return f;
  }));

  var name_st = feature.get('id');
  var name_file =  ee.String(name_st).cat('_aer_ai_timeseries');
  
  // Export to CSV
  Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: timeSeries,
      description: name_file.getInfo(),
      folder: 'Aerosol_data',
      fileNamePrefix: name_file.getInfo(),
      fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });

  return(0);
  
};
```

Comment: Please, mark as accepted below answer. It works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do client-side iteration. You can for instance create a client-side list of the gauge IDs, and iterate over that, exporting the time-series for each. Note that I pass the client-side `id` to the function, so you don't have to `getInfo()` to create a client-side string for the `description` and `fileNamePrefix` export properties.

```
gauges.aggregate_array('id').evaluate(function (ids) {
  ids.map(function (id) {
    var gauge = gauges.filter(ee.Filter.eq('id', id))
    AER_AI_series(gauge, id)
  })
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c6157cee3336ffadebee9f8ef61641f9

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I finally understood the use of 'evaluate'. Thanks.