# Select the "id" of a collection of images to export them with their corresponding "id" automatically in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I have just started to learn about Google Earth Engine and I have a problem in my code.

The code accesses the Sentinel-1 catalog, applying some filters and a crop depending on the study area. On this clipping, a loop is applied to be able to export all the images to google drive.

My problem is that I can not export the image with its corresponding "id".

I have tried to store the "id" in a variable and to select the elements of the list that contains the "id" but it does not recognize it when I put it in description to export it.

[image]

```
var fecha_ini = '2018-10-01';

var fecha_fin = '2018-10-12';

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                          .filterDate(fecha_ini,fecha_fin)
                          .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass','DESCENDING'))
                          .filterBounds(Andalucia_agua)
                          .select('VV');

print(dataset)                         
var clip = function(image){
  
    return image.clip(Andalucia_agua);
};

var dataset_clip = dataset.map(clip);

Map.addLayer(dataset_clip.select('VV'),{min:-50,max:0}, 'Escena', false);


var lista = dataset_clip.toList(dataset_clip.size())

var i;

var imagen;

for (i = 0; i< numero_imagenes; i++) {

  var imagen = ee.Image(lista.get(i))

  var id = print(imagen.id())

  Map.addLayer(imagen.select('VV'),{min:-50,max:0}, 'Escena_0'+ i )

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: imagen,
    description: id,
    scale: 10,
    region: Andalucia_agua,
    maxPixels: 1E10
});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand. You want the exported images to each have their ID as the name that matches that of the band the come from in the collection. So if band 1 in the collection was `ID` = "001", you want the image that is exported from band 1 to have the name "001"? If that's the case, technically, it might not be possible, but this might be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415186/keeping-the-actual-band-names-in-gee-exported-images/430527#430527

Answer (score 3):

The code as follows uses the 'forEach' method to iterate a list with the corresponding ids. It also selects from the id image (by using slice method) only the date because the id, as string, is too long. It also includes a not recommend 'getInfo' method. However, it works without any problem.

```
var Andalucia_agua = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-6.181516998737666, 37.22475726749809],
          [-6.181516998737666, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.22475726749809]]], null, false);

var fecha_ini = '2018-10-01';
var fecha_fin = '2018-10-12';

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                          .filterDate(fecha_ini,fecha_fin)
                          .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass','DESCENDING'))
                          .filterBounds(Andalucia_agua)
                          .select('VV');

print(dataset);                         

var clip = function(image){
  
    return image.clip(Andalucia_agua);

};

var dataset_clip = dataset.map(clip);

Map.addLayer(dataset_clip.select('VV'),{min:-50,max:0}, 'Escena', false);

var lista = dataset_clip.toList(dataset_clip.size());

print(lista);

var ids = lista.map(function (ele){
  
  return ee.String(ee.Image(ele).id()).slice(17,25);
  
});

ids.getInfo().forEach(function (c) {
  
  var idx = lista.indexOf(c);
  
  var image = ee.Image(lista.get(idx));

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'image'.concat('_', c),
    scale: 10,
    region: Andalucia_agua,
    maxPixels: 1E10
  });

});
```

Your code also works as follows but, it's even worse. The use of for-loops is [discouraged in Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_js_03) and it is necessary to employ two 'getInfo'.

```
var Andalucia_agua = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-6.181516998737666, 37.22475726749809],
          [-6.181516998737666, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.22475726749809]]], null, false);

var fecha_ini = '2018-10-01';
var fecha_fin = '2018-10-12';

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                          .filterDate(fecha_ini,fecha_fin)
                          .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass','DESCENDING'))
                          .filterBounds(Andalucia_agua)
                          .select('VV');

print(dataset);                         

var clip = function(image){
  
    return image.clip(Andalucia_agua);

};

var dataset_clip = dataset.map(clip);

Map.addLayer(dataset_clip.select('VV'),{min:-50,max:0}, 'Escena', false);

var lista = dataset_clip.toList(dataset_clip.size());

print(lista);

var i;

var numero_imagenes = lista.size();

for (i = 0; i< numero_imagenes.getInfo(); i++) {

  var imagen = ee.Image(lista.get(i))

  var id = imagen.id();

  Map.addLayer(imagen.select('VV'),{min:-50,max:0}, 'Escena_0'+ i )

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: imagen,
    description: id.getInfo(),
    scale: 10,
    region: Andalucia_agua,
    maxPixels: 1E10
});
}
```

**Editing Note:**

Based in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445926/exporting-within-a-mapped-function-in-gee/445965#445965), I found out a better way to do that. Code looks as follows:

```
function setId (img) {
  
  return img.set({'id': img.id()});
  
}

var Andalucia_agua = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-6.181516998737666, 37.22475726749809],
          [-6.181516998737666, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.21341126336629],
          [-6.153879517048213, 37.22475726749809]]], null, false);

var fecha_ini = '2018-10-01';
var fecha_fin = '2018-10-12';

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                          .filterDate(fecha_ini,fecha_fin)
                          .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation','VV'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass','DESCENDING'))
                          .filterBounds(Andalucia_agua)
                          .select('VV')
                          .map(setId);

print(dataset);

dataset.aggregate_array('id').evaluate(function (ids) {
  ids.map(function (id) {
    var img = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('id', id));
    exportImages(img, id);
  });
});

function exportImages(img, id) {
 
 print(id);

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: img,
    description: 'image'.concat('_', id),
    scale: 10,
    region: Andalucia_agua,
    maxPixels: 1E10
  });
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it works perfectly now